# Error in XSD custom type declaration

Tags: xml, xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Person">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="address" type="Address"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
 <xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="line1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="line2" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="postcode" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In this XSD definition I am unable to understand this error: 
Type 'Address' is not defined as root item within this schema or any included or imported 
schemas.

I suppose the type declaration is provided in the same schema. But what is wrong with this declaration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a local element declaration

```
<xs:element name="address" type="Address"/>
```

but there is no complexType definition with name="Address".

I suspect that the element declaration

```
<xs:element name="Address">
    <xs:complexType>
    ...
```

should probably be

```
<xs:complexType name="Address">
   ...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Person">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
                <xs:element name="address" type="Address"/>
            </xs:all>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Address">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="line1" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="line2" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="state" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="postcode" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```